# grails spring-security-oauth-facebook:0.2

Tags: facebook, grails, oauth, spring-security

I've been trying to implement the grails plugin spring-security-oauth-facebook:0.2 and am not getting successful authentication from the spring plugin. I can access facebook, enter in my credentials successfully, but when facebook redirects back to my local site, I get the standard ROLE_ANONYMOUS assigned and redirected to the login page. The standard site login through spring security works perfectly.

```
I'm using Grails 2.4.4
BuildConfig.groovy applicable plugins are:
        compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC4'
        compile ":spring-security-oauth:2.1.0-RC4"
        compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"
        compile ':spring-security-oauth-facebook:0.2'

Config.groovy:
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.myapp.domain.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.myapp.domain.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.myapp.domain.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll'],
    '/login/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/logout/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/register/**':                   ['permitAll'],
    '/oauth/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/oauth/facebook/**':             ['permitAll']
]

def appName = 'myapp'
def baseURL = grails.serverURL ?: "(myurl):${System.getProperty('server.port', '8050')}/${appName}"
oauth {
  debug = true
  providers {
      facebook {
          api = gweb.FaceBookCustomAPI
          key = 'my-key'
          secret = 'my-seceret'
          successUri = "/oauth/facebook/success"
          failureUri = "/oauth/facebook/failure"
          callback = "${baseURL}/oauth/facebook/callback"
      }
  }
}
// Added by the Spring Security OAuth plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauth.domainClass = 'com.myapp.domain.OAuthID'
```

When I click on the facebook link to login (url: /oauth/facebook/authenticate?redirectUrl=) I get the below logs:

```
....matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher Request '/oauth/facebook/authenticate' matched by universal pattern '/**'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/authenticate?redirectUrl= at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository No HttpSession currently exists
context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/authenticate?redirectUrl= at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/authenticate?redirectUrl= at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/authenticate?redirectUrl= at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/authenticate?redirectUrl= at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/authenticate?redirectUrl= at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/authenticate?redirectUrl= at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/authenticate?redirectUrl= at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/facebook/authenticate?redirectUrl=; Attributes: [permitAll]
intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor Previously Authenticated: grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@dc4337e: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] one can reach [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] in zero or more steps.
intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor Authorization successful
intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/authenticate?redirectUrl= reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
gweb.FaceBookCustomAPI AuthorizationUrl: facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123MYCLIENTID123&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocal.myappname.com%3A8050%2Fgweb%2Foauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback api key: 123MYCLIENTID123 seceret: d3996df187347f9f6b8021dd223acdf5
access.ExceptionTranslationFilter Chain processed normally
context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher Request '/oauth/facebook/callback' matched by universal pattern '/**'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/callback?code=AQCgtBI6VeUcWF7xUN5G4n9IU3Owyjm9HiM3OiPWvI2-w5FILyeqNEYPKOgDVGvyLShnNBcwzTjgPuJLls-9VFXrVCQrH4nWOzbUmUukoJVusMQUXhX6fjO_XY8a21VuJh9RkpTg-isZCSSEe86Nz9rbF4c9NK_-GRUa0onNwAbzvMSUG-IqzfzZaxyFoDcBWxS6VDuZrqVyFKEiTa0mgDjRgCZ077KMLdWJn8tWB8E9jR59CnWrvpXvfpcHz4w5NWmfmKE7Johh9ymYn8YeLr0L_7OlSydDQAyO-ERJf2JTvraQzNY0e-CA2SxTWL4lVxw at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@28b44fe3. A new one will be created.
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/callback?code=AQCgtBI6VeUcWF7xUN5G4n9IU3Owyjm9HiM3OiPWvI2-w5FILyeqNEYPKOgDVGvyLShnNBcwzTjgPuJLls-9VFXrVCQrH4nWOzbUmUukoJVusMQUXhX6fjO_XY8a21VuJh9RkpTg-isZCSSEe86Nz9rbF4c9NK_-GRUa0onNwAbzvMSUG-IqzfzZaxyFoDcBWxS6VDuZrqVyFKEiTa0mgDjRgCZ077KMLdWJn8tWB8E9jR59CnWrvpXvfpcHz4w5NWmfmKE7Johh9ymYn8YeLr0L_7OlSydDQAyO-ERJf2JTvraQzNY0e-CA2SxTWL4lVxw at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/callback?code=AQCgtBI6VeUcWF7xUN5G4n9IU3Owyjm9HiM3OiPWvI2-w5FILyeqNEYPKOgDVGvyLShnNBcwzTjgPuJLls-9VFXrVCQrH4nWOzbUmUukoJVusMQUXhX6fjO_XY8a21VuJh9RkpTg-isZCSSEe86Nz9rbF4c9NK_-GRUa0onNwAbzvMSUG-IqzfzZaxyFoDcBWxS6VDuZrqVyFKEiTa0mgDjRgCZ077KMLdWJn8tWB8E9jR59CnWrvpXvfpcHz4w5NWmfmKE7Johh9ymYn8YeLr0L_7OlSydDQAyO-ERJf2JTvraQzNY0e-CA2SxTWL4lVxw at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/callback?code=AQCgtBI6VeUcWF7xUN5G4n9IU3Owyjm9HiM3OiPWvI2-w5FILyeqNEYPKOgDVGvyLShnNBcwzTjgPuJLls-9VFXrVCQrH4nWOzbUmUukoJVusMQUXhX6fjO_XY8a21VuJh9RkpTg-isZCSSEe86Nz9rbF4c9NK_-GRUa0onNwAbzvMSUG-IqzfzZaxyFoDcBWxS6VDuZrqVyFKEiTa0mgDjRgCZ077KMLdWJn8tWB8E9jR59CnWrvpXvfpcHz4w5NWmfmKE7Johh9ymYn8YeLr0L_7OlSydDQAyO-ERJf2JTvraQzNY0e-CA2SxTWL4lVxw at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/callback?code=AQCgtBI6VeUcWF7xUN5G4n9IU3Owyjm9HiM3OiPWvI2-w5FILyeqNEYPKOgDVGvyLShnNBcwzTjgPuJLls-9VFXrVCQrH4nWOzbUmUukoJVusMQUXhX6fjO_XY8a21VuJh9RkpTg-isZCSSEe86Nz9rbF4c9NK_-GRUa0onNwAbzvMSUG-IqzfzZaxyFoDcBWxS6VDuZrqVyFKEiTa0mgDjRgCZ077KMLdWJn8tWB8E9jR59CnWrvpXvfpcHz4w5NWmfmKE7Johh9ymYn8YeLr0L_7OlSydDQAyO-ERJf2JTvraQzNY0e-CA2SxTWL4lVxw at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/callback?code=AQCgtBI6VeUcWF7xUN5G4n9IU3Owyjm9HiM3OiPWvI2-w5FILyeqNEYPKOgDVGvyLShnNBcwzTjgPuJLls-9VFXrVCQrH4nWOzbUmUukoJVusMQUXhX6fjO_XY8a21VuJh9RkpTg-isZCSSEe86Nz9rbF4c9NK_-GRUa0onNwAbzvMSUG-IqzfzZaxyFoDcBWxS6VDuZrqVyFKEiTa0mgDjRgCZ077KMLdWJn8tWB8E9jR59CnWrvpXvfpcHz4w5NWmfmKE7Johh9ymYn8YeLr0L_7OlSydDQAyO-ERJf2JTvraQzNY0e-CA2SxTWL4lVxw at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/callback?code=AQCgtBI6VeUcWF7xUN5G4n9IU3Owyjm9HiM3OiPWvI2-w5FILyeqNEYPKOgDVGvyLShnNBcwzTjgPuJLls-9VFXrVCQrH4nWOzbUmUukoJVusMQUXhX6fjO_XY8a21VuJh9RkpTg-isZCSSEe86Nz9rbF4c9NK_-GRUa0onNwAbzvMSUG-IqzfzZaxyFoDcBWxS6VDuZrqVyFKEiTa0mgDjRgCZ077KMLdWJn8tWB8E9jR59CnWrvpXvfpcHz4w5NWmfmKE7Johh9ymYn8YeLr0L_7OlSydDQAyO-ERJf2JTvraQzNY0e-CA2SxTWL4lVxw at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/callback?code=AQCgtBI6VeUcWF7xUN5G4n9IU3Owyjm9HiM3OiPWvI2-w5FILyeqNEYPKOgDVGvyLShnNBcwzTjgPuJLls-9VFXrVCQrH4nWOzbUmUukoJVusMQUXhX6fjO_XY8a21VuJh9RkpTg-isZCSSEe86Nz9rbF4c9NK_-GRUa0onNwAbzvMSUG-IqzfzZaxyFoDcBWxS6VDuZrqVyFKEiTa0mgDjRgCZ077KMLdWJn8tWB8E9jR59CnWrvpXvfpcHz4w5NWmfmKE7Johh9ymYn8YeLr0L_7OlSydDQAyO-ERJf2JTvraQzNY0e-CA2SxTWL4lVxw at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/facebook/callback?code=AQCgtBI6VeUcWF7xUN5G4n9IU3Owyjm9HiM3OiPWvI2-w5FILyeqNEYPKOgDVGvyLShnNBcwzTjgPuJLls-9VFXrVCQrH4nWOzbUmUukoJVusMQUXhX6fjO_XY8a21VuJh9RkpTg-isZCSSEe86Nz9rbF4c9NK_-GRUa0onNwAbzvMSUG-IqzfzZaxyFoDcBWxS6VDuZrqVyFKEiTa0mgDjRgCZ077KMLdWJn8tWB8E9jR59CnWrvpXvfpcHz4w5NWmfmKE7Johh9ymYn8YeLr0L_7OlSydDQAyO-ERJf2JTvraQzNY0e-CA2SxTWL4lVxw; Attributes: [permitAll]
intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor Previously Authenticated: grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@dc6f3f8: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@255f8: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: AE8351B5D34F45ED370ED63F6FB7C3A8; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] one can reach [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] in zero or more steps.
intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor Authorization successful
intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/callback?code=AQCgtBI6VeUcWF7xUN5G4n9IU3Owyjm9HiM3OiPWvI2-w5FILyeqNEYPKOgDVGvyLShnNBcwzTjgPuJLls-9VFXrVCQrH4nWOzbUmUukoJVusMQUXhX6fjO_XY8a21VuJh9RkpTg-isZCSSEe86Nz9rbF4c9NK_-GRUa0onNwAbzvMSUG-IqzfzZaxyFoDcBWxS6VDuZrqVyFKEiTa0mgDjRgCZ077KMLdWJn8tWB8E9jR59CnWrvpXvfpcHz4w5NWmfmKE7Johh9ymYn8YeLr0L_7OlSydDQAyO-ERJf2JTvraQzNY0e-CA2SxTWL4lVxw reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
gweb.FaceBookCustomAPI accessTokenEndpoint: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
access.ExceptionTranslationFilter Chain processed normally
context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher Request '/oauth/facebook/success' matched by universal pattern '/**'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/success at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@28b44fe3. A new one will be created.
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/success at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/success at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/success at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/success at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/success at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/success at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
web.FilterChainProxy /oauth/facebook/success at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/facebook/success; Attributes: [_DENY_]
intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor Previously Authenticated: grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@dc6f3f8: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@255f8: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: AE8351B5D34F45ED370ED63F6FB7C3A8; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] one can reach [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] in zero or more steps.
access.ExceptionTranslationFilter Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.access.vote.AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.decide(AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.java:47)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://local.myappname.com:8050/gweb/oauth/facebook/success]
access.ExceptionTranslationFilter Calling Authentication entry point.
web.DefaultRedirectStrategy Redirecting to 'local.myappname.com:8050/gweb/login/auth'
context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
context. ..... this seems to repeat a couple more times...
```

I am at a loss, it appears as if the Facebook authentication is working. I can kill my FB session/remove the app from my profile, and when I try the authenticate URL from my site everything appears to work, but I always just get redirected to my login screen with the above logs. Am I missing some part of the implementation?

Comment: So when FB replies back to the callback url, the code that handles that call back must reauthenticate the user.  Somewhere you must be saving the fb information and tying to your own user somehow.  What I do is capture the FB uid, save it an associate it to my own user and then call the following:  springSecurityService.reauthenticate("some user name")  I've my all my users have a unique username.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing this exact same problem for days but I think I have it solved: The answer is that the plugin does not seem to correctly handle the "Annotation" securityConfigType.

So, in order to get it to work you need to change:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Annotation"
to
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"

And then you need to convert your grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules configuration to grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap and then port your annotation based security from your controllers to this configuration as well.

This is the only way in which I could get this plugin to actually work. Hope this helps.